# I can't enable javascript on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, wine

I am trying to get my page work on IE8 and above, I rewrote my code in pure javascript but it still does not work. I am on a mac so I am trying that in Wine IE8 is that works like the one on Windows I am not sure.

By the way I have tried to enable javascript in IE8 by enabling "Allow Scriptlets" in Tools > Security > Custom Level menu.

Comment: Why do you want to use IE8 on linux? It's a very old version (11 is acutal I think). On my google search I saw that the 8 has several problems with JS, other versions (even 7) do not. Can't you upgrade? (And no I don't want to start a discussion about what is the best browser).

Comment: Ok. First of all i don't want to use it on linux what i am trying to do is test my code in ie8 on mac. I don't have a windows pc that is why. And the problem is the user uses the ie, not me.